# Django Fullcalendar - render on more than one html

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views, fullcalendar

I have an HTML page where my calendars are rendered with no problems at all.

But, I want to preview all of my calendars to another page also, something like {% include %}(which won't work).

Is there any way to do that without making another function, and render it separately?

This is my calendars.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Kalendar {% endblock title %}



{% block content_row %}
    <!--------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR LINKS ---------------------------------------------->
    {% include 'main/partials/_link_fullcalendar.html' %}
    <!--------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR LINKS END ------------------------------------------>

    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Uspešno!</strong> {{ message }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if calendars %}
        {% for cal in calendars %}
            <script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('{{ cal.id }}');
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    let calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        minTime: "07:00:00",
                        maxTime: "22:00:00",
                        businessHours: {
                            startTime: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                            endTime: '21:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
                        },
                        height: 'auto',
                        locale: 'sr',
                        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
                        defaultView: 'timeGridThreeDay',
                        header: {
                            left: 'today',
                            center: '{{ cal.name|title }}',
                            right: 'dayGridWeek,timeGridThreeDay'
                        },
                        views: {
                            timeGridThreeDay: {
                                type: 'timeGrid',
                                duration: {days: 3},
                                buttonText: '3 Dana'
                            }
                        },
                        navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                        editable: false,
                        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                        eventTextColor: 'black',
                        events: [
                            {% for i in events %}
                                {% if i.calendar_id == cal.id %}
                                    {
                                        id: "{{ i.event_id }}",
                                        calendar: "{{ i.calendar }}",
                                        calendar_id: "{{ i.calendar_id }}",
                                        title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
                                        start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
                                        end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',

                                    },
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        ]
                    });
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    calendar1.render();
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                })
                ;
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div style="display: flex; overflow-x: scroll; height: 800px" class="container">
        {% for cal in calendars %}
            <p>{{ cal.name|title }}</p>
            <div class="container" id='{{ cal.id }}'></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <!---------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR SCRIPT----------------------------------------------->
    {% include 'main/partials/_fullcalendar_script.html' %}
    <!---------------------------------------------- FULLCALENDAR SCRIPT END ------------------------------------------>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the page where I want to preview them, so the user can see available dates before scheduling.

I just want to make another div next to this one where the form is, and place my calendars inside, so the user can have two divs next to each other, one with the form, and another with the calendars and available slots.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Zakaži {% endblock title %}



{% block content_row %}
    <div style="display: flex;" class="flex-container">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'main:add_event' opp.pk %}">
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Potvrdi</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content_row %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot that I can put the calendar.objects.all() into the view where I need to render all the calendars.